# Expected value of the product of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Assume we have random variables $$X_i \,\,\,\ \text{ i.i.d } \,\,\ i\in[1:n]$$
with expected value $$\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{2}$$

Now let us compute the following expected value of the product of two random variables$$\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2] \stackrel{(a)}{=} \mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]=\frac{1}{4}$$

If I want to generalize to a product of $n$ random variables

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left( X_i\right)= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2} $$

so for $n=2$ (to double check with the example above), I have that the expected value of the product is $\frac{1}{2}$ which is wrong, where is the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^2 \frac{1}{2}$ is in fact $\dfrac14$ ( a different

Comment: I would think it is $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. The product of $\dfrac12$ taken $n$ times is $\left(\dfrac12\right)^n$

Comment: @Henry Yes, you are.  $\prod_{i=1}^n a = \underbrace{a\cdot a\cdots a}_{n\text{ terms}}=a^n$ Thus $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac 1 2 = 2^{-n}$

Comment: Why...how... do we have two different Henry?

Comment: @Graham Kemp: It is a nice name - I do not mind sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a summary of the comments,

$\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2}$ is the product of $n$ terms each of which is $\dfrac12$, so it is $\left(\dfrac12\right)^n$.

In particular $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^2 \frac{1}{2} =\dfrac14$ and not $\dfrac12$.